# Illegal mix of collations error when attempting to view MYSQL table data in Sql Developer using connector/j 8.0.16

Tags: mysql, sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer 18.1, I'm trying to view table data in a third party mysql database, but receive the following error for all tables in all 8 schemas on the database.

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and
>   (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like' vendor code 1267

My suspicion is that this is due to one schema having the utf8_general_ci DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME and the other 7 having utf8_unicode_ci. I figure that if I connect to just one schema at a time then the problem will go away, however, SQL developer seems intent on showing me all schemas, despite me selecting just one in the 'Choose database' dropdown. Using 'show jdbc' I can see the jdbc url as follows:

```
jdbc:mysql://host.comp.com:1234/?serverTimezone=UTC#/schema6
```

Yet SQL Developer still lists all 8 schemas and lets me open them up etc.

To confuse the matter, I'm already injecting the 'Port' dropdown on the connection screen to avoid the error 'The server Time Zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized'. My port value is:

```
1234/?serverTimezone=UTC#
```

Does anyone know how I can a) connect to just a single schema and/or b) specify a connection property that avoids the 'illegal mix' error?